# How to do an if statement within Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have my roles table (which to me was poorly planned) which consists of 4 fields: role_name, type1, type2, type3.

Each typeX either has a Y for yes or N for no.

Sample data:

```
Hero, Y, N, N
Human, N, Y, N
Dog, Y, N, N
```

I'd like my output to be:

```
Hero Type1
Human Type2
Dog Type1
```

Help?  Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`IIF`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) statement for this, and in your case you must nest them. 
Something like:

```
select role_name,
    iif(type1 = "Y", "Type1", iif(type2 = "Y", "Type2", iif(type3 = "Y", "Type3", "unknown")))
from roles
```

Comment: Hm, Access is throwing #Error in each row

Comment: Nevermind, got it.  Data type was yes/no and was valued at -1/0.  Oops.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested [IIF statements](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) to acheive this

```
SELECT role_name, iif(type1='Y', "Type1", 
                  iif(type2='Y', "Type2", "Type3"))
FROM roles
```

or if you want to know that no type was assigned

```
SELECT role_name, iif(type1='Y', "Type1", 
                  iif(type2='Y', "Type2", 
                  iif(type3='Y', "Type3", "N/A")))
FROM roles
```

However this does assume that you will never have someone with multiple types...

Comment: Does it matter if type1, type2, type3 have Data Type as Yes/No?

Comment: You could evaluate it as true false in that case, IE iif(type1, "Type1" etc.  No need for any equality checks (Unless no default is specified then you have nulls)